# Plotting the path left by a vector rotating around the z axis and towards the xy plane with tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, vector, tikz-3d

I have a vector along the z axis and I want to show the path traced by the point of this vector while it is spiraling down towards the xy plane. In theory, this path should be traced on the surface of a sphere having its center on the origin of said vector. How can I plot it?

I have a similar picture, you can see the path left by the rotation of the red vector.

Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the function that generates your spiral, so this is an example which I hope will be easy to modify as you need.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
%\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{130}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,tdplot_main_coords]  
  \def\r{2} % sphere radius
  % sphere
  \draw[gray]   (0,0,0) circle (\r cm);
  % axes
  \draw[dashed] (0,0,0)  -- (\r,0,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0,0)  -- (0,\r,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0,0)  -- (0,0,\r);
  % spiral
  \draw[thick,red] plot[domain=0:720,samples=100,smooth] ({\r*cos(\x)*cos(0.125*\x)},{\r*sin(\x)*cos(0.125*\x)},{\r*sin(0.125*\x)});
  % vectors
  \foreach\x in {20,120,350,660}
  {%
    \draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- ({\r*cos(\x)*cos(0.125*\x)},{\r*sin(\x)*cos(0.125*\x)},{\r*sin(0.125*\x)});
  }
  % axes again
  \draw[-latex] (\r,0,0) -- (1.5*\r,0,0) node [left]  {$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,\r,0) -- (0,1.5*\r,0) node [right] {$y$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0,\r) -- (0,0,1.5*\r) node [above] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you switch the two group of 3d coordinates provided by `\tdplotsetmaincoords` you can get these pictures:
[image]

**Edit:** I included `tikz-3dplot` as the OP requested.